# Comparing dates in the same column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query:-

```
select 
    item.HeadID as headId,
    item.STARTDate as itemStartDate,
    item.ENDDate as itemEndDate,
from 
    serv.HEAD head
inner join 
    serv.ITEM item on item.HeadID = head.HeadID
```

The result set I get is this:

| headId | itemStartDate | itemEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 197418 | 2022-10-01 | 2027-09-30 |
| 197418 | 2022-10-01 | 2027-09-30 |
| 297419 | 2022-11-11 | 2027-05-20 |
| 297419 | 2022-11-11 | 2027-05-20 |

How do I modify my query to find out if there are any rows in the table where the `headId` is same but the startdate or the enddate is different.

For example:

| headId | itemStartDate | itemEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 432561 | 2022-01-12 | 2026-05-25 |
| 432561 | 2022-02-14 | 2027-09-26 |

I want to confirm if any rows like above exists in the table.

Answer (score 0):

We could use you query as CTE, then we make a self-join to get the expected output :

```
 WITH CTE AS (
  select 
    item.HeadID as headId,
    item.STARTDate as itemStartDate,
    item.ENDDate as itemEndDate,
  from 
    serv.HEAD head
  inner join 
    serv.ITEM item on item.HeadID = head.HeadID
)
select c.*
from CTE c
INNER JOIN CTE t ON t.headId = c.headId 
  AND ( t.itemStartDate <> c.itemStartDate or t.itemEndDate <> c.itemEndDate)
```

Comment: I need to compare dates in the same column, which means comparing `item.STARTDate` with `item.STARTDate` or comparing `item.ENDDate` with `item.ENDDate`

Comment: Could you check my update

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:

Firstly, we add `DISTINCT` to receive unique rows.

```
select DISTINCT 
item.HeadID as headId,
item.STARTDate as itemStartDate,
item.ENDDate as itemEndDate,
from serv.HEAD head
inner join serv.ITEM item
on item.HeadID = head.HeadID
```

Secondly, we use this query in `FROM` to find duplicated HeadID.

```
SELECT A.HeadID, COUNT(*) AS No_Rows
FROM (
select distinct 
item.HeadID as headId,
item.STARTDate as itemStartDate,
item.ENDDate as itemEndDate,
from serv.HEAD head
inner join serv.ITEM item
on item.HeadID = head.HeadID
) A
GROUP BY A.HeadID
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

If there is any No_Rows > 1, you have in your results HeadIDs with different dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this. It only requires a single scan of the base table, **no joins needed**.

```sql
select *
from (
    select 
      item.HeadID as headId,
      item.STARTDate as itemStartDate,
      item.ENDDate as itemEndDate,
      minStart = min(item.STARTDate) over (partition by item.HeadID),
      maxStart = max(item.STARTDate) over (partition by item.HeadID),
      minEnd   = min(item.ENDDate  ) over (partition by item.HeadID),
      maxEnd   = max(item.ENDDate  ) over (partition by item.HeadID)
    from
      serv.ITEM item
) item
where (
    item.minStart <> item.maxStart
 or item.minEnd   <> item.maxEnd
);
```